# Web API Attribute Routing multiple controller types were found when using query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm getting a 500 error back from Web API ""Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested"

Ok, so I looked at my controllers, thinking I had botched a routing attribute.  Except, everything looks ok.  Here are the 2 actions that are in conflict (if I comment one of them, then the endpoint works)

Here's the one that's returning the 500

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("foo/bar/{id?}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFooByIdAsync(string id) {}
```

This one works, but if I don't comment it out, the other one gives a 500:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("foo/{id?}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFooByIdAsync(string id){}
```

My one clue:  the paths really are the same, so the first segment in the url for both is "foo/"

Now here's the even crazier part:

If I use this url, both endpoints work fine:

```
http://domain.com/foo/bar/anId
```

But if I use a query string, I get my 500 error:

```
http://domain.com/foo/bar?id=anId
```

Can anyone explain what is going on, and how to get my url to work with a query string?

**additional info:** the `id` used to be an `int`, and the path worked with an `{id:int?}` route constraint, but due to a design change, the `id` had to become a `string` (it's now an encoded string). I am having trouble working out a constraint that will work.

It's a base-64 string, with the padding removed, and with '/' and '+' transformed to '_' and '-' respectively (Base64-url encoded)

Comment: because it doesn't know if `bar` is the inline `id` parameter of the second route or the url segment of the other route regardless of query string. You need to uniquely identify the routes to avoid conflicts. To get it to work with query string remove inline parameter or use route constraints

Comment: @Nkosi I suspected something like that when I was troubleshooting, and I looked at route constraints, but I could not seem to find a constraint that would work.  A little additional info:  the id used to be an int, and the path worked with an {id:int?} route constraint, but due to a design change, the id had to be come a string (it's now an encoded string).  I am having trouble working out a constraint that will work.  It's a base-64 string, with the padding removed, and with '/' and '+' transformed to '_' and '-' respectively.

Comment: create a custom constrain for base64-url encoded string. that should make it unique enough

Comment: Start here for learning how to create your custom constraint https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints

Comment: I'm looking into the custom constraint.  Here's a crazy thing:  If I configure the same route as above using the conventions based routing, it works fine. (I'd much rather use the attribute routing though, for readability)